# Custom Validation using Trigger throwing System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, before-trigger, opportunity-history

I am trying to addError on the opportunities based on one condition. But getting System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors error while saving the record. Below I have given the code snippet. Please let me know how I can resolve the issue.

```
if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore){
        map<Id,Opportunity> newOpptyMap = (map<Id,Opportunity>)trigger.newMap;
        OpportunityTriggerHelper.checkforStageDuration(newOpptyMap,Trigger.OldMap);
    }
```

The function is below where I am adding the error statement

```
public static void checkforStageDuration(Map<Id,Opportunity> oldMap, Map<Id,Opportunity> newMap){
        Map<Id,Opportunity> recordsToCheck = new Map<Id,Opportunity>();
        for(Id oppId : newMap.keyset()){
            if(newMap.get(oppId).StageName != oldMap.get(oppId).StageName){
                recordsToCheck.put(oppId,newMap.get(oppId));
            }
        }
        List<Opportunity_Stage_History__c> oppStageHistory = [select Id,Expected_Stage_Duration__c,Opportunity__c,Duration__c,Reason_For_Delay__c from Opportunity_Stage_History__c where Opportunity__c IN :recordsToCheck.keyset()];
        for(Opportunity_Stage_History__c oppHistory : oppStageHistory){
            if(oppHistory.Duration__c>oppHistory.Expected_Stage_Duration__c && oppHistory.Reason_For_Delay__c==null){
                newMap.get(oppHistory.Opportunity__c).addError('The Opportunity has crossed it\'s Stage Duration, Please fill the Reason for Delay !!');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling addError on `Trigger.OldMap` instead of `Trigger.NewMap`. When declaring the signature for `checkForStageDuration` you have it (oldMap, newMap) but when you are passing in parameters in your trigger, you are passing in (newMap, oldMap).